# Android photoviwer VIEW intent only showing 1 image

Tags: android, image, android-intent

In my android app, I create an intent to display an image in the photogallery app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///storage/sdcard0/arin/category/1/1.png"), "image/*");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the photo app and shows that image but only that image...
I know there are other images in the same folder. But the app wont let swipe left/right and switch images. How can I change the code so it will let me see the other pics in the same folder...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I change the code so it will let me see the other pics in the same folder

Write your own "photogallery" code.

There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of apps that are capable of responding to your `Intent`. None of them have to offer any means to "swipe left/right and switch images". If you want a specific set of behaviors, write them yourself. If you want the *user* to be able to view the image in the *user's* chosen app, then stick with your existing code and do not worry about the behavior of the *user's* chosen app.

Comment: But the regular "gallery" android app does have the swipe left and right feature to switch images, which is what I want. The weird this is in the intent which opens up the `same` app, it disables the swipe left/right...

Comment: @omega: That behavior is up to the authors of that gallery app, not you.